# Timestamp в git commit через git config --global alias

Tags: git, bash, alias

Господа, подскажите если кто знает как плз.

```
git config --global alias.com "commit -a -m \"$(date +\"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y\")\""
```

Дает в результате timestamp создания алиаса в коммите

```
git config --global alias.com "commit -a -m \"\$(date +\"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y\")\""
```

равно как и

```
git config --global alias.com 'commit -a -m "$(date +"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y")"'
```

Дает в коммите собственно `"$(date +"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y")"`.

работает нормально башевский алиас

```
alias gcom='git commit -a -m "$(date +"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y")"'
```

но если есть возможность сделать это через git alias хотелось бы сделать именно так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в тексте псевдонима может быть только одно из двух: или команда для программы *git*, или команда для оболочки (в этом случае текст должен начинаться с символа `!`).

но внутри команды оболочки, конечно, можно выполнить (в том числе) и программу *git* с нужными аргументами, например:

```
!git commit -m текст
```

---

для вашего примера команда создания псевдонима может быть такой:

```
$ git config --global alias.com '!git commit -m $(date +"%H:%M:%S_%d-%m-%Y")'
```

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает